# gulp-babel plugin doesn't work

Tags: gulp, babeljs

I try to use babel with gulp. But I faced error that can't resolve.

My gulp task looks like 
`

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    babel = require("gulp-babel");

gulp.task('default', function() {

    gulp.src(cssSrc)
        .pipe(concat('main.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));

    gulp.src(jsSrc)
        .pipe(babel())
        .pipe(concat('app.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));

    gulp.watch(cssSrc,['css-task']);
    gulp.watch(jsSrc,['js-task']);

});
```

`

jsSrc - array of pathes to js files

.babelrc looks so

```
{
"presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

When I run gulp I see this error

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
ReferenceError: [BABEL] C:\workspace\projects\test\test-client\app.js: Unknown option: C:\workspace\projects\test\test-client\.babelrc.presets
    at Logger.error (C:\workspace\projects\test\test-client\node_modules\gulp-babel\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\logger.js:58:11)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (C:\workspace\projects\test\test-client\node_modules\gulp-babel\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:126:29)
    at OptionManager.addConfig (C:\workspace\projects\test\test-client\node_modules\gulp-babel\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:107:10)
    at OptionManager.findConfigs (C:\workspace\projects\test\test-client\node_modules\gulp-babel\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:168:35)
    at OptionManager.init (C:\workspace\projects\test\test-client\node_modules\gulp-babel\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:229:12)
    at File.initOptions (C:\workspace\projects\test\test-client\node_modules\gulp-babel\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:147:75)
    at new File (C:\workspace\projects\test\test-client\node_modules\gulp-babel\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:137:22)
    at Pipeline.transform (C:\workspace\projects\test\test-client\node_modules\gulp-babel\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\pipeline.js:164:16)
    at DestroyableTransform._transform (C:\workspace\projects\test\test-client\node_modules\gulp-babel\index.js:30:20)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (C:\workspace\projects\test\test-client\node_modules\gulp-babel\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:172:10)
```

app.js- the first file in jsSrc array

What could be wrong ?

Comment: Remove `"presets": ["es2015"]` from `{"presets": ["es2015"]}` and leave `{}` in _.babelrc_ , which will still compile.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as you described.

In my case, the solution was in addition to updating module `babel-cli` also to update module `gulp-babel` to the latest version with `npm install gulp-babel --save-dev`, as they [updated](https://github.com/babel/gulp-babel/commit/94addacf32c6671eaba2329a75b419f194fdaeab) the core library to 6.0.*.

Hope that helps!

Comment: yes, update gulp-babel to version 6, resolve my problem